# How can I get my SVG path to scale to fit?

Tags: image, image-processing, svg

I've done my best to bring this down to a minimal working example, but please excuse the wall of code at the bottom. I've got a set of paths, in this particular case they spell the word "DOG". I'd like to scale them to fit in a box *without preserving aspect ratio*.
For example, with a suitable definition of `DOG` I get:

```
 <g>
   <svg height="141.23" width="400.0" x="0.0" y="0.0">
     <rect height="100%" width="100%"
      stroke='black' fill='purple'/>
     <use xlink:href="#DOG"/>
   </svg>

   <svg height="73.34" width="210.81" x="189.18" y="273.94">
     <rect height="100%" width="100%"
       stroke='black' fill='purple'/>
     <use xlink:href="#DOG"/>
   </svg>
 </g>
```

[image]

I cannot figure out, using `preserveAspectRatio='none'` or any other tricks to get my `DOG` in the (lower) window to fit exactly. The result is always clipped. I can try to guess at a `viewBox` but this is brittle, shouldn't I be able to do this at the upper level of the DOM here?

The complete code for the SVG is listed below:

```
<svg version="1.2" width="400.0pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <g>
   <svg height="141.23" width="400.0" x="0.0" y="0.0">
     <rect height="100%" width="100%"
      stroke='black' fill='purple'/>
     <use xlink:href="#DOG"/>
   </svg>

   <svg height="73.34" width="210.81" x="189.18" y="273.94">
     <rect height="100%" width="100%"
       stroke='black' fill='purple'/>
     <use xlink:href="#DOG"/>
   </svg>
 </g>

 <defs>

  <symbol id="DOG">
   <defs>
    <g>
     <symbol id="letter_D" overflow="visible">
      <path d="M 131.5 -66.953125 C 131.5 -104.609375 106.203125 -136.09375 73.71875 -136.09375 L 10.359375 -136.09375 L 10.359375 -130.90625 C 24.109375 -130.90625 26.296875 -130.90625 26.296875 -121.9375 L 26.296875 -14.140625 C 26.296875 -5.1875 24.109375 -5.1875 10.359375 -5.1875 L 10.359375 0 L 73.71875 0 C 105.796875 0 131.5 -29.484375 131.5 -66.953125 Z M 116.765625 -66.953125 C 116.765625 -38.859375 108.59375 -27.5 104.8125 -22.109375 C 100.03125 -15.9375 88.671875 -5.1875 69.734375 -5.1875 L 47.421875 -5.1875 C 39.453125 -5.1875 39.046875 -6.171875 39.046875 -12.953125 L 39.046875 -123.140625 C 39.046875 -129.90625 39.453125 -130.90625 47.421875 -130.90625 L 69.734375 -130.90625 C 86.28125 -130.90625 116.765625 -121.140625 116.765625 -66.953125 Z " style="stroke:none;">
      </path>
     </symbol>
     <symbol id="letter_O" overflow="visible">
      <path d="M 134.09375 -67.75 C 134.09375 -108.59375 104.8125 -139.28125 71.734375 -139.28125 C 37.859375 -139.28125 9.171875 -108.1875 9.171875 -67.75 C 9.171875 -27.296875 38.25 3.1875 71.53125 3.1875 C 105.609375 3.1875 134.09375 -27.890625 134.09375 -67.75 Z M 118.953125 -70.328125 C 118.953125 -22.3125 93.640625 -0.40625 71.734375 -0.40625 C 49.015625 -0.40625 24.3125 -23.109375 24.3125 -70.328125 C 24.3125 -117.359375 51.40625 -135.6875 71.53125 -135.6875 C 92.65625 -135.6875 118.953125 -116.765625 118.953125 -70.328125 Z " style="stroke:none;">
      </path>
     </symbol>
     <symbol id="letter_G" overflow="visible">
      <path d="M 136.6875 -48.21875 L 136.6875 -53.40625 C 131.90625 -53 121.140625 -53 115.765625 -53 L 87.078125 -53.40625 L 87.078125 -48.21875 L 93.046875 -48.21875 C 110.1875 -48.21875 110.578125 -46.03125 110.578125 -38.859375 L 110.578125 -25.703125 C 110.578125 -3.78125 84.6875 -2 78.5 -2 C 57.984375 -2 24.3125 -16.140625 24.3125 -68.140625 C 24.3125 -120.140625 57.390625 -134.09375 76.71875 -134.09375 C 99.21875 -134.09375 115.5625 -114.5625 119.34375 -86.875 C 119.75 -84.484375 119.75 -84.078125 121.546875 -84.078125 C 123.734375 -84.078125 123.734375 -84.484375 123.734375 -88.0625 L 123.734375 -135.296875 C 123.734375 -138.875 123.53125 -139.078125 122.34375 -139.078125 C 121.546875 -139.078125 121.34375 -138.875 119.953125 -136.484375 L 111.1875 -119.75 C 101.421875 -132.109375 89.46875 -139.28125 74.125 -139.28125 C 40.046875 -139.28125 9.171875 -109.1875 9.171875 -68.140625 C 9.171875 -27.296875 39.453125 3.1875 74.515625 3.1875 C 90.65625 3.1875 106.40625 -2.59375 112.578125 -13.953125 C 115.96875 -5.78125 121.546875 -0.203125 122.53125 -0.203125 C 123.53125 -0.203125 123.734375 -0.40625 123.734375 -3.984375 L 123.734375 -39.65625 C 123.734375 -47.21875 124.328125 -48.21875 136.6875 -48.21875 Z " style="stroke:none;">
      </path>
     </symbol>
    </g>
   </defs>
   <g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
     <use x="-10.359" xlink:href="#letter_D" y="139.247"/>
     <use x="130.512871" xlink:href="#letter_O" y="139.247"/>
     <use x="273.975031" xlink:href="#letter_G" y="139.247"/>
   </g>
  </symbol>
 </defs>

</svg>
```

Comment: Try `transform="scale(.5)"` or whatever you want.

Comment: @Shmiddty That's the problem, I don't know the "whatever I want". I want it to scale x and y so it fits exactly into the box!

Comment: @Shmiddty your snarky comment made it clear to me that I wasn't communicating well enough. If you look at the code you'll see that I don't know _a priori_ what the symbols height and width is, I need an external call to javascript it seems. This project was to done standalone using only svg commands.

Comment: @Hooked i tried the transform but i wasn't able to solve, could you post the working snippet

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use scale in the [`transform`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute) attribute in an outer `<g>` container.

```
transform="scale(x, y)"
```

With a little JavaScript, you can find the dimensions about an arbitrary path:

```
var box = path.getBBox();
var eleWidth = box.width, eleHeight = box.height;
```

Comment: But how do I know how big to scale it? Do I have to guess until I get it right? That's what I'm trying to avoid. I guess I don't know how to get at the x and y.

Comment: The values for scale are simply the width/height of the container divided by the width/height of the element inside the container, respectively. If you care about preserving the aspect ratio, choose the smaller scale.

Comment: But what is the height/width of the inside container? How do I get that out in this outer part of the DOM?

Comment: Why not just use `path.getBBox()`?

Answer (score 17):

You could also use [`ViewBox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) together with [`preserveAspectRatio="none"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) for a result that, in my opinion, almost always gives me the desired result. That way you don't have to do calculations to specify a transformation, but instead decide how big a canvas you draw on and then automaticly scaling it to the desired size...

Example:

```
<svg style="width: 500px; height: 800px;" viewBox="0 0 610 1340" preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

You know your drawing will be drawn within the viewBox sizes but the result has to be fit into a 500x800 size window with or without preserved aspect ratio.

EDIT: I know you said "without preserving aspect ratio", but you still need to decide what you want to do instead. You can scale/stretch or clip. Those options are outlined under the preserveAspectRatio specifications.

Comment: Also good resources: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio), [Making Sense of SVG viewBox's Madness](http://www.justinmccandless.com/blog/Making+Sense+of+SVG+viewBox's+Madness), [How to Scale SVG](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)

Comment: for me this destroys text quality